# How to access fields of converted JSON object sent in POST body?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

My Spring `@Controller` needs to access fields of a passed object in JSON format. I would like to avoid building many classes to map every request response to. For example, I need to connect store two foreign keys. They are passed as `{"key1": 1,"key2": 2}` to the controller. How to access those fields if I don't have an object which has 2 fields to map those properties? How to set up the Spring controller method?

My code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProductPart", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addProductPart(Model model, @RequestBody Object json,
                                 BindingResult result){

        // access somehow key1 and of json Object
```

**UPDATE:**
I know I can get it working using `RequestMethod.GET` and `@RequestParam`, but since I modify data I need `RequestMethod.POST` or `RequestMethod.PUT`.

**SOLVED:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProductPart", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addProductPart(Model model, @RequestBody Object   obj){
...
int p = (Integer)((Map)obj).get("part");
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring, by default, uses Jackson to deserialize JSON. If you specify `Object` as the parameter type, Jackson will deserialize the JSON to a `LinkedHashMap`. You can cast the variable and access the elements through `Map#get(Object)`.

Alternatively, you can declare your method parameter as some POJO type that fits the JSON structure and Jackson will deserialize to that type. You can then use its getters to retrieve your data.

Comment: Can you please provide code example how to get element with given name from `Object` or casted `LinkedHashMap` to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProductPart", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String addProductPart(@RequestBody GetData obj){
   System.out.println(obj.jObj.getString("key1"));
}
```

Here `GetData` is class that will receive data in it & map incoming data in it.

`GetData class` :

```
public class GetData{
  private JSONObject jObj;

  //getter-setter

  // if you are getting more than one element or array of json then :

  private JSONArray jArray();
  // getter-setter
}
```

if you want JSonArray then you can make operation on it.

It's related code tutorial is [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm).

Still some problem then post me.

You can also use directly `JSonObject` in method Invocation but if you are getting more data then it's better to use Class & pass it to there.

One thing to keep in mind that the Name of received `JSonObject` & the Name `declared in class` should be same.

Some problem POST me.

Comment: Why I cannot cast like this `@RequestBody (JSonObject)Object   obj`? Not OK fot IDE also `@RequestBody JSonObject   obj`. How to work around that?

Comment: @RCola - Have you try `@RequestBody JSonObject obj` ? It will i think work. If it is then read data from it otherwise post me.

Comment: It requires some additional dependencies I cannot get working. See update - solution I ended up with. Thanks!

Comment: Have you add dependency of `Jackson` ? for `JSON serialize` & `deserialize`.

Comment: I have `jackson-mapper-asl` , `jackson-databind`

Comment: I am using from `org.codehaus.jackson` & working fine.